# Summarize and subtract with NA

Tags: r, count, na, addition, subtraction

can anyone help?

I have a dataset

```
x <- data.frame(A = c(NA, '1', '0', '0'),
            B = c('0', '0', '0', NA),
            C = c('1', NA, NA, NA))
```

I need to generate something like this (generate the two variables x5 & x6):

```
 _ x1 x2 x3 x4  x5 x6
A  NA 1  0  0   1  2
B  0  0  0  NA  0  3
C  1  NA NA NA  1  0
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the meaning of `x5` and `x6`? How you get the values in these two columns?

Comment: This is what I want to know.
x5 is the counting of 1s, 
x6 is the counting of 0s
I need to generate x5 and x6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the comment that you were still working on this. The answer by @ThomasIsCoding works just fine, but just in case, here's an alternative, step-by-step approach you could also consider.

First, transpose your data frame (we'll call `df`):

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(x))
df

    V1   V2   V3   V4
A <NA>    1    0    0
B    0    0    0 <NA>
C    1 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

Now for the 2 additional columns, use `rowSums` to sum up the values of "1" and "0". You need `na.rm = TRUE` given presence of `NA` in your data. The value `1:4` represents the first four columns.

```
df$V5 <- rowSums(df[,1:4] == "1", na.rm = T)
df$V6 <- rowSums(df[,1:4] == "0", na.rm = T)
df
```

**Output**

```
    V1   V2   V3   V4 V5 V6
A <NA>    1    0    0  1  2
B    0    0    0 <NA>  0  3
C    1 <NA> <NA> <NA>  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the code below

```
setNames(
  cbind(
    data.frame(t(x)),
    t(sapply(x, function(v) table(factor(na.omit(v), levels = c(1, 0)))))
  ),
  paste0("x", 1:6)
)
```

which gives

```
    x1   x2   x3   x4 x5 x6
A <NA>    1    0    0  1  2
B    0    0    0 <NA>  0  3
C    1 <NA> <NA> <NA>  1  0
```

Comment: Hi, I am sorry, I am very new to R...
Where in the coding do I add the 'x's?
My data set is huge, therefore I will have to identify my used variables.

Comment: @Alessa `x` is prefix of column names, which is added when using `setNames`

Comment: I know but would I insert the first name of the columns?

Comment: What do you mean "insert the first name of the columns"? @Alessa

Comment: I mean in my example would I write 
setNames(
  cbind(
    test.df(t(x1)),
    t(sapply(x1, function(v) table(factor(na.omit(v), levels = c(1, 0)))))
  ),
  paste0("x", 1:6)
)

Comment: @Alessa What is `test.df` in your code? A function? If your dataframe is named as `x`, you can just replace `x` by `x1` in my code

Comment: test.df = name of the dataframe
x1 = column 1
x2 = column 2
...

I just don't understand how I can make your code work for my dataset.

At the moment I seem to do something wrong:

setNames(
  cbind(
    data.frame(t(w1_data_tb$f1roster)),
    t(sapply(w1_data_tb$f1roster, function(v) table(factor(na.omit(v), levels = c(1, 0)))))
  ),
  paste0("x", 1:6)
)

My outcome looks like this:
 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 NA NA NA

Comment: @Alessa Then you should try `setNames( cbind( t(test.df), t(sapply(test.df, function(v) table(factor(na.omit(v), levels = c(1, 0))))) ), paste0("x", 1:6) )`

Comment: Thanks, for your input. I will keep trying to figure it out. I still get only NAs in my output.